# Regex : Get value of last bracket from the string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to extract the last group bounded by brackets from the string. The string could be like one of these variants:

```
String                             ' Extracted sub
--------------                     ' -------------
Some (text)                        ' text
Some (text) (here)                 ' here
```

I need the substring between the last closing bracket from the string

I have tried this regex code but it is always fetching the values from first bracket in the string

```
public static getValueInsideBracket(str: string): string {
    let isStringHaveBrackets: string[];
    if (!str) {
      return '';
    }
    isStringHaveBrackets = str.match(/(.*)\(.*\)/);
    if (isStringHaveBrackets) {
      return str.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1];
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can use `split()`

Comment: is there is no regex method? @HarunurRashid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 /\(([^()]*)\)$/
```

Explaination: 
Look for an open ( and match everything in between it that isn't ( or ) and then has a ) at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
\(([^)]+)\)?(){1}$
```

You have missed to add `?(){1}$`. which will give you the last occurence

```js
function getValueInsideBracket(str){
    if (!str) {
      return '';
    }
    let isStringHaveBrackets = str.match(/(.*)\(.*\)/);
    if (isStringHaveBrackets) {
      return str.match(/\(([^)]+)\)?(){1}$/)[1];
    }
  }
console.log(getValueInsideBracket('hi (some) (text) (read)'))
```